# Encrypt with GPG using BouncyCastle(neuhalfen)

Tags: java, encryption, gnupg, openpgp

I am trying to encrypt a file using neuhalfen bouncy castle openpgp library, 2.3.0

I get an error No (suitable) public key for encryption to demouser found.

The steps, I have followed on a mac are:

1. gpg --gen-key (create key)
2. gpg --export -a demouser > demouser-public.key (export public key)
3. gpg --export-secret-keys demouser > demouser-private.key (export private key)

I am able to encrypt and decrypt using gpg

1. gpg -e -r "demouser" test.csv
2. gpg -d test.csv.gpg > test_dec.csv

With Java, I tried:

```
    public void encryptFileWithGPG(String inputFile, String encryptFile, byte[] pubKey, byte[] privateKey) throws IOException, PGPException, SignatureException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

        final InMemoryKeyring inMemoryKeyring = KeyringConfigs
                .forGpgExportedKeys(KeyringConfigCallbacks
                        .withPassword(""));
        inMemoryKeyring.addPublicKey(pubKey);
        inMemoryKeyring.addSecretKey(privateKey);

        try (final FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(encryptFile);
             final BufferedOutputStream bufferedOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutput);
             final OutputStream outputStream = BouncyGPG.encryptToStream()
                     .withConfig(inMemoryKeyring)
                     .withStrongAlgorithms()
                     .toRecipient("demouser").andSignWith("demouser")
                     .binaryOutput()
                     //.armorAsciiOutput()
                     .andWriteTo(bufferedOut);
             final FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile)
        ) {
            Streams.pipeAll(is, outputStream);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas, with the No (suitable) public key found with above code?

I managed to get it to work with just Bouncy Castle, but it was more complicated.

Comment: Did you see the full running examples for Bouncy Castle (https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/tree/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples), they helped my a lot in PGP file encryption ?

Comment: Could you add the keys (demouser-public.key and demouser-private,key) to your question as well? That is, only if those are not valuable of course. No suitable public key might mean that there is no encryption or signing capable subkey found.

Comment: You could also try another library such as [PGPainless](https://github.com/pgpainless/pgpainless) (disclaimer: author here).